# Can I use Google Analytics for long-polling my visitors?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm running an online music compilation archive. Visitors can download and stream the audio. When streaming, visitors are able to keep browsing the site, but sometimes the page is just kept open in a browser tab. Each compilation is between 20 minutes and 3 hours long.

I suspect Google Analytics becomes untrustworthy after a couple of minutes. The 'Real-Time Overview' no longer shows these users as active. Also, duration on the page seems to be updated when they load a *new* page. But more often than not, the site is exited after listening to compilation, losing the duration information.

What can I do to more accurately track my visitors' behavior? Can I periodically let GA poll the visitor and update their session and page duration?

**Update:**

I had already increased my session timeout to the maximum allowed length of 4 hours, as can be seen below:

[image: Session settings]

Answer (score 1):

The real time reports show users who are currently active and doing some activity. The reason why users disappear is because they are inactive for 30 mins and their session times out.

One thing you can do is increase your session duration to 3 hours

here's how you can increase your session duration
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795871?hl=en

and real time reporting
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1638635?hl=en

secondly you can use the user id view in GA
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123662?hl=en

Here's how you can setup user id view
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123666?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timer and have it trigger a GA event. There are two ways to implement this, depending on how you want to read the data.

1. Tag Manager timers. Set intervals: 30 seconds, 1 minute, 2 minute, 5 minute, etc. Set up an event report for each and attach it to a trigger that fires after x number of seconds.
2. Rather than set up timed intervals, you can create a script that'll poll with events.

As a long winded example (requires analytics.js has been loaded):

```
// This will count the number of times the function runs.
pageTimer = 0;
// Periodically run the function
window.setInterval(function(){
  // Increment the counter
  pageTimer = pageTimer + 1
  // Assumes it runs every 30 seconds
  theNow = pageTimer * 30
  ga('send', {
    hitType: 'event',
    eventCategory: 'Timer',
    eventAction: theNow + ' seconds on page',
    eventLabel: 'Video name?'
  });
}, 30000); // Run every 30 seconds
```

That code should be optimised before use - I've written it the long way to demonstrate it's workings.

Comment: Making custom events sounds like a good way to do this. Could you please elaborate (preferably in-answer) what this will look like in Google Analytics? Judging by your code, events will be grouped by occurrences per 30 seconds. So something like 50 hits on `30 seconds on page`, 35 hits on `60 seconds per page`, 20 hits on `90 seconds per  page`, and so on. Mind that my audio is **very long** so this would results in enormous amounts of different event actions. I think this answer could be improved it the data was eventually aggregated in a more useful way.

Comment: It all depends on how you want to aggregate it. Theoretically, you could create an event for when the page unloads that'll tell you how long they sat around for. But how do you want that labelled and presented? I recommend choosing your increments and adjusting around them.